# div boxes aligned below each another, not next to each other

Tags: html, css

I need to make a video box area but I can't do this because my div boxes are not side by side.

My outcome looks like this:
[image]

```css
.vidcontainer {
  position: relative;
  fload: left;
  weight: 1200;
  height: 300;
  margin: 240 auto;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.vidcontainer .vidbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 370;
  fload: left;
  height: 370;
  background: #161616;
  fload: center;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="vidcontainer">
  <div class="vidbox"></div>
  <div class="vidbox"></div>
  <div class="vidbox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are typos in your code : `fload`-->`float` ; `weight`-->`font-weight`/`width`(don't know what you intended to write) and its value is between between 100 to 900 with a step(increment) of 100 . And `px` left off in the shadows

Comment: I suggest you try to get familiary with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code contain many typos aswell as invalid values. All the syntax erros, typos and invalid values should be fixed first.

Comment: ok sorry for typos i don't have good english.

Comment: @MrEnoX typos in the comments are no problem... typos in code are :-) check the highlighting of your code and you see 'fload' and 'weight' are black, not purple. So there's something wrong.

Comment: also to add to the list: `float: center` is an invalid value too. the `float`-property only has `left` or `right`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your CSS is missing a lot of "px" and has a few of typos (weight instead of width, fload instead of float).
I suggest you use flex instead of floating elements. here is my solution.

```css
.vidcontainer{
  position:relative;
  width:1200px;
  /*height:370px;*/
  margin:240px auto;
  background:#ddd;
  border-radius:15px;
  display: flex;
}

.vidcontainer .vidbox{
  position:relative;
  width:370px;
  height:370px;
  background:#161616;
  margin:15px;
  border-radius:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="vidcontainer">
  <div class="vidbox"></div>      
  <div class="vidbox"></div>
  <div class="vidbox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it works as well <3
Can you do something to make it go to the bottom line when there are 2 of these in a line?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. you wanted all of them in one line if I understood your question right.